# adding same fragment more than once at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am designing an alarm application.

I am working with a fragment that acts as my alarms, the idea is to use the same one for each new alarm (i don't know if this is the right way).

Well, then i am basically trying to add, via pressing a "new alarm" button, the same fragment again into the layout of an activity, but when i press the button the app crashes. Any help?

I am inserting the fragment into a LinearLayout that is inside a ScrollView that is inside of the RelativeLayout

```
package com.example.roo.proyi;

import android.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class alarms extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarms);



        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        alarm_fragment alarmFragment = new alarm_fragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer,alarmFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Button button_newAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_new_alarm);
        button_newAlarm.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alarm_fragment alarmFragment2 = new alarm_fragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer,alarmFragment2);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }

                    ;
                }
        );

.
.
.
.
.
.CONTINUES BUT IT IS IRRELEVANT
.
.
.
```

FINAL SOLUTION MADE BY CREATING A DIFFERENT FRAGMENTTRANSACTION

```
public class alarms extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarms);



        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        final alarm_fragment alarmFragment = new alarm_fragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer,alarmFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Button button_newAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_new_alarm);
        button_newAlarm.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        alarm_fragment alarmFragment2 = new alarm_fragment();
                        fragmentTransaction2.add(R.id.alarmListContainer,alarmFragment2);
                        fragmentTransaction2.commit();
                    }

                    ;
                }
        );
```

Comment: Probably would use a `ListView` and add your alarms to a custom adapter.

Comment: would help if you posted your logcat

Comment: @ColinGillespie How do you suggest doing that? i tried but it crashes at the oncreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same `FragmentTransaction` to add the fragment inside of your `OnClickListener`. Once you call `commit()` on a transaction, you cannot use it again. Call `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` to get a new transaction.

Comment: Great, this worked, as a reference to other people i will post the modified code (at least what i modified in order to try your solution, i know it is not clean)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out -

1. It checks whether you have added a dialog fragment in the stack already or not. If yes, it will remove the fragment and add new fragment with a new `argument`, if it does not exist, it will add the fragment anyway.

see if you could incorporate this approach in your code -

```
    void showDialog() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

[Source is Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)